TLS connection between IBM-Datapower and IBM-MQ
I am working on IBM Datapower GatewayScript which posts messages to IBM MQ and there is a consumer GatewayScript which is invoked every second using XML Manager periodic schedule policy rule. The message producer GatewayScript is invoked as part of assembly processing while processing the HTTP request. I am using urlopen.open() to post messages to MQ in producer GatewayScript, and also in the consumer GatewayService to pull messages from MQ. This is working fine without TLS.
I am trying to enable TLS between Datapower and MQ. For this, I have set up MQ correctly, as I am able to establish TLS connection with MQ server using openssl client. I have created a TLS client profile in Datapower and using the 'sshClientProfile' option in urlopen.open(), but is not working. I captured network traffic and observed that TLS connection is not even attempted between Datapower and MQ. The Datapower Client sends INITIAL_DATA message and MQ server responds with STATUS_DATA with 'Close Chnl' and 'Error' flags set. The connection is closed after that. I tried different options but no success so far.
What is the reason for this problem? How can I enable TLS connection between Datapower and IBM MQ? Please help.

I thought the sshClientProfile was for SFTP - what makes you think it would be used to MQ?

Is this what you are doing? https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/datapower-gateway/10.6.0?topic=module-urlopenopen-connect-target-servers Should you use sslClientProfile?
